# How can I upload Zoom videos recorded locally to YouTube automatically?

Tags: video, youtube, zoom-meeting

I would like to upload videos recorded locally with Zoom to YouTube (unlisted) automatically. I would also then like the videos to be removed from my hard drive automatically once uploaded as well. I know that automatic uploads to YouTube is possible with their API, and in fact Zapier has an action for this. However, I'm not sure how to trigger this — or whether a script would do this job.